# Вывод числа с ведущими нолями

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть некий диапазон чисел, допустим, 0–100.

Нужно вывести последовательно эти числа в формате вида `000, 001, 002, ... 100`. То есть идет заполнение справа-налево (не знаю как это называется).

Я понимаю, что можно условием все прогнать, но получается не так красиво.

```
for i in range(101):
    x = i
    
    if i < 10:
        x = '00' + str(i)
    elif i >= 10 and i <=99:
        x = '0' + str(i)

    print(x)
```

А если числа не до 100, а до 1 000 000? Или вообще не известен диапазон? Есть ли иное решение?

Answer (score 11):

Для Python >= 3.6, используйте [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
>>> x = 10
>>> print(f'{x:05}')
                ^ желаемая длина строки
00010
```

или метод [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) строки, который работает в любой версии:

```
'{:05}'.format(10)   # '00010'
    ^ желаемая длина строки
```

---

**Более подробно:**

Желательно знать или вычислить максимальное количество позиций, которое потребуется для вывода числа `max_width`.

Если есть отрицательные числа, нужно учитывать, что знак будет занимать одну из позиций. Можно сделать так, чтобы знак выводился всегда.

Для дробных чисел нужно учитывать позицию для точки (запятой).

```
max_width = 5
print(f'{10:0{max_width}}')      # 00010   - вывод с добавлением нолей
print(f'{-10:0{max_width}}')     # -0010   - минус забирает одну позицию
print(f'{-10000:0{max_width}}')  # -10000  - если число слишком большое, 
                                 #           строка будет длиннее, чем max_width
print(f'{10:+0{max_width}}')     # +0010   - обязательный вывод знака
print(f'{10.5:0{max_width}}')    # 010.5   - точка забирает одну позицию
print(f'{10:{max_width}}')       #    10   - можно заполнять пробелами
```

---

Подробнее про возможности форматирования можно почитать в документации:

- [Описание мини-языка форматирования](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)
- [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)
- [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: Если хочется запретить float, то явно формат можно указать: `'{:03d}'.format(1.0)` (ValueError). Или чтобы формат не нарушать, сравните с `"%03d" % 1.0` -> `001`

Answer (score 5):

У строк есть метод `zfill`, который как раз этим и занимается

```
zeros_count = int(input('Сколько нулей нужно? '))
for x in range(101):
    print(str(x).zfill(zeros_count))
```

(В случае, если число нулей заранее известно и планируется использовать эту строку с другими строками, возможно `format` из соседнего ответа будет предпочтительнее)

Бонус: ещё есть методы `ljust(количество, символ)` и `rjust(количество, символ)`, которые добавляют не только нули, но и любые указанные символы справа и слева от строки соответственно

```
'foo'.ljust(5, '-') == 'foo--'
'foo'.rjust(7, '+') == '++++foo'
```

Comment: `zfill()` в отличии от `rjust('0')` умеет со знаками работать. `"+1".zfill(3)` -> `"+01"` vs. `"+1".rjust(3, '0')` -> `"0+1"` Если ввод число, то проще сразу отформатировать: `"%03d" % x`

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 1
str = "%03d" % i
print str
Результат : 001
```

Answer (score 2):

В принципе можно ещё попробовать сложением строк.

Примерно так:

```
n = input()
m = int(input('до скольки символов заполнять'))
n ='0'*(m-len(n)) + n
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте методы строк `rjust()` или `ljust()`

```
for i in range(1,11):
    #нужно дополнить нулями до 3 цифр
    print(str(i).rjust(3,"0"))
```

описание метода https://pythonstart.ru/string/ljust-rjust