# Как запретить убирать цифру ноль в начале числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

```
l = []
a = int(input())
l.append(a) 
print(l)
```

В итоге выводит не "**`000123`**", а "**`123`**"

Comment: вводите строку а не число. int () уберите перед инпутом во 2й строке

Comment: либо храните строки вместо чисел, либо сами выводите 3 нуля в начале

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628701/314323

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Дополнительные нули к числам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628701/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Comment: У чисел в начале нет нулей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
_str = input('Введите несколько чисел через пробел: ')

_list = list(map(int, _str.split()))

_format = '{}'.format('{:05}\n'*len(_list))

print(f'{_format}'.format(*_list))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это уже есть в базовой комплектации. S.zfill(width) Делает длину строки не меньшей width, по необходимости заполняя первые символы нулями. print('123'.zfill(5))